# How do I input OBS virtual cam in my python code using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a code for detecting the color green from a live video. I want to make a detector so that whenever the color green pops up in the screen, a counter starts counting how many times the color appears.

So for the video source, I am using the OBS Virtual Camera. But I have no idea how to input it as the source. I have seen codes inputting web cams as the source as shown below:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
  
  
# Capturing video through webcam 
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Anyone have any idea how I can input the OBS virtual cam? Or does anyone know any alternative like switching to another language to do said task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows will treat OBS Virtual Camera as a regular camera. The argument for `cv2.VideoCapture` is camera number. So up that number by 1 over and over again until the program uses the OBS Virtual Camera. And there you go.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that there is a bug currently reported that opencv is not parsing the stream from OBS virtual cam and just showing a black background.

https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/issues/3635

Comment: Do you know any fix for this? I'm using ffmpeg until this bug is fixed, but the issue got closed a while ago and there doesn't seem like a lot of hope

Comment: Yes, there is a plugin called virtual camera (the same name as the built-in function) that works, i'm trying to find the link. I'll post it whcen i get it.